# ¿Por qué falla este condicional?

Tags: bash

Supongamos el siguiente **código**:

```
# Comprueba que el archivo existe y se puede leer
function fileExist(){
        if [[ ! -e ${PATH}/$1 || ! -r ${PATH}/$1 ]]
                then echo "ERROR_505"
                        echo "Fichero no accesible"
                        exit 5
        fi
}
```

He comprobado que **los datos son correctos al entrar a la función** añadiendo la línea *echo ${PATH}/$1* justo antes del condicional: la ruta (*${PATH}/$1*) llega bien y es correcta. Sin embargo, a pesar de que el archivo $1 existe y es legible, se mete en el condicional e imprime el error (pero no debería).

¿Por qué el condicional no funciona? Gracias.

Comment: Dudo que tenga nada que ver, pero segun parece no puedes hacer un exit de lo que quieras, tan solo del 0-255. Mira aqui: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2242

Comment: Sí, es cierto. Sin embargo, lo he cambiado y sigue fallando el condicional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se encierra un condicional `||` entre doble corchetes `[[]]` ésta operación no funciona como se espera a menos que la operación sea con [operadores de cadenas de texto o aritméticos](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

En este caso estas usando [operadores de testeo de archivos](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html), y por lo que parece la primera línea debe ser así para ejecutarse correctamente:

```
if [ ! -e $VEAMOS ] || [ ! -r $veamos ]
```

[En este enlace](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) encontrarás más información sobre las construcciones de testeo.